# How install GTK+ 3 for Python

Tags: application-development, python, gtk, gtk3

I'm start programming in Python and I want learn GTK+ 3. I'm using a Distro based on Ubuntu 12.04 ([Elementary OS](http://elementaryos.org/)) and I'm having some troubles to install GTK+ 3 in Python.

Okay, I will show you what I'm trying do.

**First ->** [Following this tuto](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html), I wrote this simple code for generate a Window using GTK+ 3.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    from gi.repository import Gtk

    win = Gtk.window()
    win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

**Second ->** I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    win = Gtk.window()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 243, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._introspection_module, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 105, in __getattr__
    self.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'window'
```

**Third ->** Trying to find the error, I found [this guide](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) that I skipped before try to run "main.py". I'm trying to follow this guide because I don't know if Elementary (Ubuntu 12.04) have GTK+ 3, PyGObject and other things necessary for develop GTK+ 3 applications with Python, by default.

**Forth ->** Summarizing, I'm having problems trying to install JHBuild. I successfully followed [this guide of how to install Jhbuild](https://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/unstable/getting-started.html) until 2.1 item. But when I try to run

```
jhbuild sanitycheck
```

I have the following error message:

```
jhbuild: could not load config file, /home/paladini/.jhbuildrc is missing
```

How can I solve this issues and finally use GTK+ 3 with Python?

Comment: Maybe you should give part 2.2 of the JHBuild install instruction another try, save a copy of their `examples/sample.jhbuildrc`  as `~/.jhbuildrc` and try again, won't hurt much.

Comment: Thanks @arsaKasra, but Timo already solved my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a problem with your installation, but with your code.

Change

```
win = Gtk.window()
```

to

```
win = Gtk.Window()
```